# Max Min Ant System for TSP Optimisation

Tags: artificial-intelligence, evolutionary-algorithm, ant-colony

I have implemented an Ant System algorithm to solve the TSP which obtains tour results only about 5% longer the optimum tour (acceptable). Now I am trying to implement the similar [Max Min Ant System algorithm](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/277284831_MAX-MIN_ant_system).

The algorithm I have implements works as follows:

```
func UpdateMaxMin {
    // decay pheromone
    graph.decayPheromone()

    // get best path from this iteration
    bestPath = paths[0]
    for path in paths {
        bestPath = path.length < bestPath.length ? path : bestPath
    }

    // update for only the best path (sometimes use the global best)
    if random(0, 10) > 8 {
        graph.updatePheromone(globalBestPath)
    } else {
        graph.updatePheromone(bestPath)
    }

    // clamp pheromone levels between min and max
    graph.clampPheromone()

    // check for stagnation
    if graph.checkStagnation() {
        // update max
        max = 1 / (rho * globalBestPath.Length)
        // reset all pheromones to max
        graph.SetPheromoneMatrix(max)
    }
}
```

However, the algorithm stagnates *far* too quickly (after only a few iterations) and once it has stagnated, the max pheromone becomes a tiny number (smaller than min).

From what I have found online I am using a pheromone decay rate of `rho = 0.5` and initialising `max` to a large number and `min` to

```
    a := antCount
    p := math.Pow(0.05, 1/a)
    min = max * (1 - p) / (((a / 2) - 1) * p)
```

Besides this, the actual amount of pheromone which the best ant deposits on each edge in their tour is calculated by:

```
    deposit = 1 / tour.Length
```

However, this value is *much much much* too small to actually create a distinct best path - for example, if the pheromone starts at 5, after the first tour it will decay to 2.5 and the best ant will lay down about 0.001 pheromone on relevant edges. Even if I multiply the deposit by the number of ants a huge number of ants is required to create a significant change.

The results of my MMAS are better than random but much worse than the vanilla AS. The MMAS constructs tours about twice as long as the optimal tour.

Could anyone point out my mistake (or suggest improvements) to my algorithm?